# delete from a table where the primary key doesn't exists in another table as a foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

I hope someone can answer me, I'll be thankful.

I'm working on a mysql exercise, I've stuck into a problem, I have to delete a rows from a table called "tbl_1" where two conditions, `year = 2019` and `tbl_1.id` not exists in `tbl_2.id`, here is my query:

```
DELETE from tbl_1 where year(date1) = "2019" and not exists    
 (select id from tbl_2 join tbl_1
  on tbl_2.id = tbl_1.id);
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS` you should use a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE 
FROM tbl_1 
WHERE YEAR(date1) = '2019' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_2 WHERE tbl_2.id = tbl_1.id)
```

Or with a `LEFT` join where you filter out the matching rows:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tbl_1 t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_2 t2 
WHERE YEAR(t1.date1) = '2019' AND t2.id IS NULL
```